# Access data from Viewbag Dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dropdown, viewbag

I am getting the value from dropdown to controller but when it goes back to View it returns Null
SCREENSHOT OF VIEW:-
[image]

SCREENSHOT OF CONTROLLER:-

```
public ActionResult Index(int departmentID)
{
     ViewBag.dropdowndetail = null;
 
    var strDDLValue = departmentID;
    if (strDDLValue == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        var emp = db.employees.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.depId==departmentID);
        return View(emp);
    }
}
```

ERROR:
[image]

Comment: Be more descriptive

Comment: From dropdownlist i want show the data of only those employee whose ID I am selecting through Dropdownlist
Inshort I want to search through dropdown

Comment: @KhizarNayyar do you mean when you `POST` the form data and then return to the View, the dropdown data is `null`? If so, this is because you ALSO need to populate `ViewBag.dropdowndetail` on the `POST` action before you return the View. ViewBag only lasts for the current request.

Comment: You mean In the Post Index method I should use ViewBag.dropdowndetail as well?

Comment: @KhizarNayyar yes, you need to populate it in there as well if you intend to use it again in the View of that Controller method. ViewBag will be empty when you `POST` the form

Comment: Ok thanks Let me check.

Comment: Error concurring value cannot be null in the view

Comment: @KhizarNayyar it would be better if you could update your question with the current View and Controller source code (not images)

Comment: Updated and also mentioned the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get it right
My viewbag was not getting any value in Post method so that why in View it was getting null Exception
I call my viewbag in Post method and give it the value.
change the following code with this.

```
 public ActionResult Index(int departmentID)
    {         
        var strDDLValue = departmentID;
        if (strDDLValue == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            var emp = db.employees.Where(x=>x.depId==departmentID).ToList();
            ViewBag.dropdowndetail = db.departments.Distinct().ToList();
            return View(emp);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyvalue approach in controller

```
ViewBag.dropdowndetail = db.departments.Distinct().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.depid, x.DepartmentName));
```

and in View use ViewBag like this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.depid, new SelectList((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>)ViewBag.dropdowndetail , "key", "value"), "--Select Departments--")
```